# IE9 javascript nested `createElement` fails

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-9

I have 2 nested `with` statements each one has a `createElemet` function, it runs correctly in every browser except IE9, in IE9 it doesn't even give a error, what's the problem?

the code:

```
with(block = document.createElement('div')){
    with (detaildiv = document.createElement('div'))
    {
        alert('test');
    }
}
```

Comment: BTW you shouldn't use `with` at all. It's better to write down all names, especially for these five lines.

Comment: @ComFreek it's just a stripped-down version of a long code that I included in my project.

Comment: A [blog post](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2006/04/11/with-statement-considered-harmful/) from Douglas Crockford about why `with` shouldn't be used:

Comment: FYI, the bug has been removed in IE 10. This example works fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/HGB6z/

Comment: @ComFreek your example works in IE9 too!, I think it has something to do with two `createElement` functions in nesting `with` not just two nestig `with` statements.

Comment: @sepehr Can you show us a bit more of your code? What is the exact problem (undefined variable, ...)?

Comment: @ComFreek the problem: the alert funciton in above sample doesn't execude in IE9.the cause is two `createElement` functions nested in two `with` statements. see [jsfiddle.net/esn2v/8/](http://jsfiddle.net/esn2v/8/)

Comment: @sepehr I can confirm that this is a bug in IE 9. It's working in IE 10 but if I switch to IE 9 via Developer Tools, the `alert()` won't work. Maybe, you could create a bug report [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9).

Comment: @ComFreek I filled up a question in there, if there's a response I will write it here,tnx.
http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/ie/forum/ie9-windows_7/nested-createelement-in-with-statement-bug/a1d86684-2046-42e6-b123-e32a95ad67cd

Comment: @sepehr I've just tested to prefix the inner `document.createElement` with `window`: `window.document.createElement` and it works fine! See http://jsfiddle.net/RfWdH/ and http://jsfiddle.net/agZkJ/!

Comment: @ComFreek thanks to your creativity my code works just fine now.pls post above comment as answer.

Comment: @sepehr Done :) Please post also a link to my answer to the bug report you opened, I think that'll be very useful for the IE developers ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already mentioned in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12227113/ie9-javascript-nested-createelement-fails#comment16396537_12227113), I found a very simple solution:

Use `window.document.***` instead of directly using `document.***` in inner `with`s:

```js
with(block = document.createElement('div')) { 
    with (detaildiv = window.document.createElement('div')) { 
        alert('test'); 
    } 
}
```

You should also consider refactoring your code and replacing the `with` statements by other constructs.

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking the problem is a bug in ie.

Practically speaking the problem is that you are writing bad code, creating nested local scopes because you can, not because you need it - with a big hit to maintainability and performance as a result.

Comment: I searched a lot but couldn't find this bug, do you have a reference for this?